# Unaligned issue about ether_addr_equal function?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm reading some articles about unaligned memory access problem and referred this article [UNALIGNED MEMORY ACCESSES](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/unaligned-memory-access.txt)

> ```
> bool ether_addr_equal(const u8 *addr1, const u8 *addr2) {
>     #ifdef CONFIG_HAVE_EFFICIENT_UNALIGNED_ACCESS
>     u32 fold = ((*(const u32 *)addr1) ^ (*(const u32 *)addr2)) |
>        ((*(const u16 *)(addr1 + 4)) ^ (*(const u16 *)(addr2 + 4)));
>     return fold == 0;
>     #else
>     const u16 *a = (const u16 *)addr1;
>     const u16 *b = (const u16 *)addr2;
>     return ((a[0] ^ b[0]) | (a[1] ^ b[1]) | (a[2] ^ b[2])) != 0;
>     #endif
> }
> ```

and it said:

> But when the hardware isn't
>   able to access memory on arbitrary boundaries, the reference to a[0] causes
>   2 bytes (16 bits) to be read from memory starting at address addr1.

Well, I DO NOT know that what it means. In my mind, `a[0]` must be read 2 bytes from `addr1`, if not, what will it read? (maybe crash, but it is a 2 bytes or nothing situation I think).  So what problem will occur here? And why don't they use `u8*` and compare one byte by one byte to solve the unaligned problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my mind,a[0] must be read 2 bytes from `addr1`,if not,what will it read?  So what problem will occur here?

The intended meaning is certainly that `a[0]` reads one byte from `addr1` and one byte from `addr1 + 1` using a 2-byte access.  A system may have a restriction that requires a 2-byte access to begin on even address boundaries.  If `addr1` is odd, that is violated.

> And why don't they use u8* and compare one byte by one byte to solve the unaligned problem?

Likely it was assumed target systems would not encounter the above problem.  Using one byte at a time would handle that case.

---

Note:It appears the two halves of the function are not functionality equivalent.  Consider data bits all zero, the first returns `true`, the 2nd returns `false`.

Comment: _"Likely it was assumed..."_ - better than that, `addr1` and `addr2` are effectively guaranteed to be at least 16-bit aligned: "It is up to the caller to ensure this alignment or not use this function at all."

Comment: @Notlikethat As the two halves of the function have different functionality, I have doubts that lower half of the function is every really used.

Comment: Indeed, I'm pretty sure nobody ever compiles documentation ;) [The real function itself is correct](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/etherdevice.h#n305).

Comment: @chux thanks for you explain.But what will happen if the addr1 and addr2 not aligned to u16?Is it depends on the architeture?

Comment: @cheneydeng Yes, architecture dependent.